# Import Madness: using absolute imports doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, import, package

recently, I was working on a project, where I had a sandbox, where I was developing my part of an application. The idea was to develop all features in that sandbox, and after tests, move it to the proper project packages.
`Please, do not discuss this approach, the main case is the import problem, not the work organisation.`

Using this approach, I get this structure of my sandbox:

```
sandbox
  |
  +- importer
      |
      +-- __init__.py       
      +-- ca
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           +-- ca.py
           +-- zombie.py
```

## Content of files:

- `importer/__init__.py`

  ```
  import importer.ca
  ```
- `importer/ca/__init__.py`

  ```
  from ca import *
  ```
- `importer/ca/ca.py`

  ```
  import importer.ca.zombie as zombie
  ```

All other files are empty.

After running python interpreter:

```
>>> import importer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "importer\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import importer.ca
  File "importer\ca\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ca import *
  File "importer\ca\ca.py", line 2, in <module>
    import importer.ca.zombie as zombie
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ca'
```

There is a sandbox directory in my `sys.path`.

When I delete content of `importer/ca/ca.py`, I'm able to import importer. 
Moreover, when I change the content of `importer/ca/ca.py` to `import importer.ca.zombie` or `import zombie` or `from importer.ca import zombie` everything work just fine.
Going further, using one of the option that actually work, then I print out my module cache:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sorted(sys.modules.keys()): print i
```

I get:

```
...
errno
exceptions
functools
genericpath
importer
importer.ca
importer.ca.ca
importer.ca.importer
importer.ca.zombie
importer.importer
linecache
locale
nt
...
```

`importer.ca.importer` and `importer.importer` are Nones. And how did ther actually go there?

So, to summarize, my question is not how to make it work, but why it works that way. Why I can't use the absolute import path `import importer.ca.zombie as zombie` and what's going on in the `sys.module` cache?

Comment: There's a duplicate (probably more) that I've seen recently, but basically, you're recursively import the `ca` subpackage. Because you're doing this at the top-level of the module(s), things break.

Comment: While you're not asking for a fix: dotted relative imports really work here. That makes the transition to Python 3 (please do) a lot easier as well.

Comment: Could you go deeper in your explanation? I'm looking for a description of low-lever mechanisms behind the scene,to fully understand, what's going on under the hood.